# How to Create an Application for the Windows Phone Marketplace?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7

Sorry for my 'hard' question, but I would like to create an application that should retrieve all product lists from an asp.net web service, then see it's description and be able to buy it with button click. The product is from my website that has a web service (asp.net). This is a description of myconcept:

> 1. There are 3 pages. Page 1 for user to sign in/sign up, page 2 is a data bound page and page 3 is for descriptions (contains image too) from page 2's item click.
> 2. In the page 2. The application can use a data bound to retrieve all product name with it's image.
> 3. In the page 3. If we click the one of items in data bound, we could see it's description and image.
> 4. Then from that, you should be able to buy that product via email with click button event (button at page 2's description).

So that is my concept, anyone have any articles or anything else for help on building this project? I would be very happy if there are any answers.

Thanks.

*Note*:

1. I am a pro for VB.NET desktop application but not a pro for Windows
   Phone apps.
2. I know how to create web services with it's retrieve data in windows phone (but I only know how to retrieve/not truly CRUD)
3. I only know VB.NET language
4. I have searched Google but couldn't find anything
5. I am confused and almost stress :D :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Visual Studio 2012 for C# and VB.net and with the proper setup of the project and selecting a option to set It to a Windows Phone App.

Note: I am not a pro at this stuff I am a Ipad/IPhone app developer.

Answer (score 0):

Right, You must use Visual studio 2012, there's a form that supported creating windows application

Note: I am not a pro at this stuff, i am a VB.net desktop and Android developer.